# Showing a quantity is independent of time to deduce form of PDE solution

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $h = h(r, t)$ be the thickness of a drop of liquid and $R(t)$ be its radius. $r$ and $t$ are the radial coordinate and time respectively. $h$ satisfies the relation
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r{h}^{3} \frac{\partial h}{\partial r} \right)
> \end{equation}
> with
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{\partial h}{\partial r} (0, t) = 0, \qquad \lim_{r \rightarrow R(t)} h(r,t){(R(t)-r)}^{-1/3} = 1
> \end{equation}
> (a) Show that $\int_{0}^{R(t)} rh(r, t)dr$ is independent of $t$.

> (b) Using the result of (a), when $f$ is continuous and $h(r, t) = f(r/{t}^{\alpha}){t}^{-1/4}$ and $R(t) = k{t}^{\alpha}$ for some constant $k$, find the value of $\alpha$. ($f$ need not be determined)

I have solved part a) of this problem, and I used the first relation and both boundary conditions to show it(so really, I should expect to rely on the information given in the next part of the question). However, I have drawn a blank as to what I should do for part b. My "trick" was to use dimensional analysis because $h$ is in metres, so the units of $f(r/t^\alpha)$ must equal $MT^{1/4}$ which implies $\alpha=-1/4$, but I'm not entirely convinced this is right.

I would greatly appreciate a small hint to get started.

EDIT:

Let $M=\int_0^{R(t)} rh(r,t)dr$ be independent of $t$ then
$$\begin{aligned}
 M &=\int^{R(t)}_0rf(r/t^\alpha)t^{-1/4}dr\\ 
&=t^{-1/4} \int^{kt^\alpha}_0rf(r/t^\alpha)dr \\
\end{aligned}$$

I'm pretty sure this is the way to go, its the only way I can think of that uses the information about $R(t)$. I also think the final blow must be to use the partial derivative relation(to get some hope at evaluating the integral), but I don't know how to proceed with that.

EDIT: Please leave any comments suggesting improvements to my question, usually questions recieve some amount of attention within a day. Is it genuinely difficult? Or have I not explained it properly?

EDIT: Working for part a)

Use the Leibnitz integral rule.
$$M=\int_0^{R(t)} rh(r,t)dr $$
$$\frac{dm}{dt}=\int^{R(t)} r\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}dr + R(t)h(R(t),t)R'(t)$$

We can use the known expression for $r\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} $ to evaluate the integral and the initial conditions to argue that these terms vanish i.e $\frac{dm}{dt}=0$

Comment: I'm curious about part (a), would you post your work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that

\begin{equation}
M=t^{-1/4}\int_0^{kt^{\alpha}}r\cdot f(r/t^{\alpha}) dr
\end{equation}
is constant. Now we substitute $y=r/t^{\alpha}$, which implies $dy=dr/t^{\alpha}$ and we get
\begin{equation}
M=t^{-1/4}\int_0^k t^{\alpha}y \cdot f(y) \cdot t^{\alpha}dy=t^{2\alpha-1/4}\int_0^ky\cdot f(y)dy.
\end{equation}
Since this expression has to be independent of $t$, we conclude that $2\alpha=1/4$.